# Quartz drawing slow on transformed view

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, quartz-2d, cgaffinetransform

If I transform a 2000x2000 `UIView` to 200x200 (using `myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(...)`), the drawing gets extremely slow.

The drawing code is pretty simple:

`-drawRect:`

```
    CGContextAddPath(context, activePath);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.strokeWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

**Do I need to do anything in particular to make drawing performance better?**

p.s. I get very good drawing performance as long as I don't transform the drawing-canvas view. i.e. approximately 60 fps.

p.p.s. The view hierarchy is something like this:

```
UIView
UIView > UIView (controls)
UIView > UIView (drawing container)
UIView > UIView (drawing container) > UIView (background view)
UIView > UIView (drawing container) > UIView (drawing canvas)
```

Maybe my drawing code is not the problem; maybe the slow-performance has something to do with my view hierarchy. I'm getting slow drawing performance even if I don't use any background image, and keep the drawing canvas's background plain White. Any tips?